# Dictionary searching with datetime keys

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, python-2.7

I have time series data that I am currently storing in a dictionary where the dictionary 'keys' are `datetime.datetime` objects. Something along the lines of:

```
data[datetime.datetime(2012,5,14,15,28,2)]={'error':error,'flags':flags,'value':value}
```

The question I have is: **What is the best way to find the closest two times (before and after) a specified time?** I need this function to be as fast a possible because it is called (~10,000) inside a loop that is linearly interpolating between the two closest points.

---

I currently have one method working which takes a ridiculously long time because it searches through all the keys (~50,000):

```
def findTime(time):
    keys=data.keys()
    bdt=10000000000000000000
    adt=10000000000000000000
    minKey=False
    maxKey=False
    for key in keys:
        dt=(time-key).total_seconds()
        if abs(dt)<bdt and dt>0:
            bdt=abs(dt)
            minKey=key
        elif abs(dt)<adt and dt<0:
            adt=abs(dt)
            maxKey=key
    return minKey,maxKey
```

---

My attempt at using bisect:

```
def findTime(time):
    keys=data.keys()
    l,r = bisect.bisect_left(time,keys), bisect.bisect_right(time,keys)
    return l,r
```

Unfortunately, this produces an error:

```
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object does not support indexing
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can sort dictionaries based on datetime objects, but have you tried that? Then you would be able to assign an index to the key you're looking up and just add/subtract the index by 1 to find the nearest times.

Comment: Can you convert the datetime dates into second offsets from a certain time? Then you can just use a float or an integer.

Comment: You can sort a dictionary by datetime objects. The problem is that the time that I want is not necessarily a key in the dictionary

Comment: I agree with drewk you should just use a timestamp instead of a datetime object

Comment: @Cryptite: Dictionaries don't have any order so sorting doesn't make sense with them.

Comment: Why not just store a sorted copy of `array data.keys()` in a variable and use that instead of doing data.keys() in the function body? That way you could just do a binary search (for nearby values) on the array (Agreed that it'll eat up some memory for ~50k entries).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bisect` functions take as their first argument a sorted array (or list, or really, anything that can be indexed).  `keys` is an unsorted array, and you're passing it as the second argument.

This should work:

```
def findTime(time):
    keys = sorted(data.keys())
    return bisect.bisect_left(keys, time), bisect.bisect_right(keys, time)
```

although you should keep the sorted copy around for repeated searches that have not altered the data, rather than re-sorting every time.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! now my algorithm is ~20 times faster.

Answer (score 3):

You are far better off using a different key for your dict.

Two are obvious.

1) You can use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format as a string. This is essentially `YYYY-MM-DD` format. You can also use `YYYY-MM-DD:HH:MM:SS` format. A property of ISO 8601 is is lexical sorting, so in a sorted list of keys just take the two sorted keys above and below the insertion point.

2) You can use a float representation of the dates with the integer part being a day offset from a millennium mark and the float being the fraction of the day which is then easily converted to HH:MM:SS. Excel and Windows and Unix use this approach.

Example of 1):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).isoformat()
'2012-05-14T13:55:22.142548'  # a hashable, sortable dict key based on time
```

Example of 2):

```
>>> time.time()               # That is days and fraction of day since 1/1/1970 
1337028447.499273             # THAT is you dict key
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=14, tm_hour=13, tm_min=52, tm_sec=13, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=135, tm_isdst=-1)
```

In either case, Python would be able to manage a data structure of 50,000 elements in milliseconds.

Convert the time stamp to a datetime object as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index based on `bisect` module seems to be a valuable idea to dig into. However, by looking at the documentation, you will see that bisect functions take a sorted list as a first argument and not in second argument.

Try:

```
keys=sorted(data.keys())
bisect.bisect_left(keys,time), bisect.bisect_right(keys,time)
```

Also, you can try to optimize your code by constructing the `keys` object outside of your `findTime` function. If you `data` dictionary is not modified through your sequence of `findTime` calls, you will pay the construction of the sorted list only once.